# Getting syntax errors when building with python 3.1 and not with python 2.6

Tags: python-3.x

Using Mac os X 10.6, python 3.1 and gcc 4.0 trying to build pyfsevent implemented in python2.6 by converting it to python 3.1.

Wondering when **getting the following errors while building in python 3.1 alone**.

**Why not when building with python 2.6?**

```
error: syntax error before ‘CFFileDescriptorRef’

warning: no semicolon at end of struct or union

error: syntax error before ‘}’ token

warning: data definition has no type or storage class
```

Answer (score 0):

The C code does not get converted when running 2to3, you need to port it manually.